# R Clustering from pairs

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

There is an issue I have not been able to solve for weeks.

I have a database of users and TV series they liked. There are many thousands users (A, B, C, D...) and thousands of TV series (1, 2, 3, 4...). So the result is  millions of pairs "user;likedseries" database. For example:

```
A;10 #user A liked series 10
A;23
A;233
A;500
B;5
B;10
B;343
C;10
C;233
C;340
...
```

I seek a method in R how to compare:

**1) Clusters of similar users based on TV series they liked**

**2) Clusters of similar TV series based on user likes**

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: If you visited the Amazon website, you'd see recommended books or something on it. A similar thing can be done and k-nearest neighbor algorithm could be one.

Comment: It is unclear from what you have provided for us, but my hunch is that the data is pretty sparse.  Random forests may work, but I suspect most of your clusters would be formed by more popular shows (and this may be fine for your first request).  For the second question something like market basket analysis, where you wouldn't necessarily partition the data but form likely relationships, such as {The Simpson's and Futurama} -> {Family Guy} might be useful.

Comment: Provided the number of TV series is orders of magnitude less than the number of users, you can use a generative model that follows Bayes' rule.  Essentially P(cluster_i) = prod(P(cluster_i(show_j))), and you randomly assign shows to a different number of clusters initially.  As long as you have a smoothing parameter (e.g., minimum probability for cluster membership of a show), you will probably be fine.  There are better ways of doing this, but this is one of the simplest ones.

Comment: This really doesn't have to do with programming specifically (just because you want to use R doesn't make it a programming problem). You really need to choose a statistical method that would be appropriate for your data. There are many clustering algorithms out there and you should know which one you want to implement before you start programming. This might be a better question for [stats.se] or [datascience.se] (but check whats on-topic there first).

Comment: Thank you very much for all comments and answers. You are right, this isn't programing question and boards like Cross Validated or Data Science would be better (I didn¨t know them).

Answer (score 1):

If you pivot your data into transactions, you have a classic scenario of market basket analysis, popular for recommender systems:

```
UserA: M1 M11 M17
```

there are plenty of algorithms and tools for this such as the arules package.

Comment: Thank you. I used Arules from Apriori library and the results are great.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a generative algorithm you could use.  You will probably want to optimize it with the `data.table` package and/or an external database if your sample size is very large.  The code was written to be relatively easy to read for beginners.

Below there are 12,000 users and 90 shows, and 5 different types of shows/users.  Each user has a 7x chance of liking a show in their category than a show outside of their category.  The resulting data frames show estimated clusters for users, probability of cluster membership for users, and probabilities that a particular show is associated with a cluster (you need to normalize the values, since the probabilities in the columns add up to 1).  [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Multinomial_naive_Bayes) is the algorithm that is used here.

```
library(plyr)

#creates "true" values
trueclass = sample(5,12000,replace=TRUE)
sid.sample <-function(x){ sapply(x,function(x) sample(1:90,1,prob = rep(1,90)*1+((0:89)%%5 == (x-1))*6))}
df = data.frame(user = rep(1:12000,each = 4),sid = sid.sample(rep(trueclass,each=4)))

#create empty frames
k = 5
uids = unique(as.numeric(df$user))
sids = unique(df$sid)

#initialize probabilities
uclass = uprobs = rdply(function() {x=rep(0,k);x[sample(k,1)] = 1;return(x)},
                        .n = length(uids))[,-1]
sprobs = matrix(0,nrow = length(sids),ncol = k)
scounts = sprobs*0

row.to.max <- function(x) rep(1,length(x)) * (1:length(x) == which.max(x))

#priors for each group; initially make them unbiased
priors = rep(0.2,5)

#slow method that still works
#20 iterations
for (counter in 1:40){
  print(counter)
  #smoothing
  scounts[,] = 1
  #calculate show probabilities
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    scounts[df[i,2],which.max(uclass[df[i,1],])]=scounts[df[i,2],which.max(uclass[df[i,1],])]+1
  }
  sprobs = apply(scounts,2,function(x) x/sum(x))
  #to calculate user probabilities
  uprobs[,] = 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    uprobs[df[i,1],] = uprobs[df[i,1],] + log(sprobs[df[i,2],])
  }
  #convert from log to actual, and add prior
  uprobs = t(apply(uprobs,1,function(x,priors,temperature){ x = x + log(priors);x=x-max(x);x=exp(x);x/sum(x)},priors = priors))
  uclass = t(apply(uprobs,1,row.to.max))
  priors = colSums(uclass)
  #small bit of smoothing
  priors = (priors+0.01)/sum(priors+0.01)
  print(priors)
}

final.classes = apply(uclass,1,which.max)
table(trueclass,final.classes)
```